# Are there any simple VST hosts that accept Open Sound Control?

Tags: vst

I'm not looking for anything fancy. Not a DAW or sequencer. Just a wrapper that will let me pipe messages coming from my controller via Open Sound Control to one of my plugins.

Comment: did you try http://www.osculator.net

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention, I was looking or something in Windows. Also I wanted an actual host. Not just just to turn OSC into, say, MIDI.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I can think of is routing an OSC-MIDI bridge like [OscVstBridge](http://opensoundcontrol.org/implementation/oscvstbridge) ([SourceForge](http://oscvstbridge.sourceforge.net/)) to a plain VST host like [Cantabile Performer](http://www.cantabilesoftware.com/) and [SAVIHost](http://www.hermannseib.com/english/Savihost.htm).

That would be nice if you could share the result or your solution.

*Note: You may make use of [this list](http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2011/05/16/bpb-freeware-studio-best-free-vst-host-applications/) of free VST Hosts.*

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Pedalboard 2](http://www.niallmoody.com/apps/pedalboard2). It's a very simple VST host which is capable of receiving OSC messages. 
Additionally, it offers an auto-learn capability, that detects the messages so you can pair them easily with your VST controls.

Answer (score 1):

Plogue Bidule seems to be exactly what you are looking, simply perfect.